# jsfiddle jquery not persisting my input field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use JSFiddle with a jQuery snippet but it is not working as expected. One thing I notice is any input doesn't persist. All this snippet does is use the .isNumeric() function of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/n50ocyv6/

**markup**

```
<input type='text' id='target'></input>
```

**script**

```
var tempVal = $('#target').val();
var isNumber = $.isNumeric(tempVal);
alert(isNumber);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "any input doesn't persist". Can you help to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle's Javascript is executing as the page loads, while the `$('#target')` input has no value.  An empty value is not numeric and fails the `$.isNumeric()` test, resulting in false.

Try adding an event listener on there to execute the code like this:

```
$('#target').change(function(){
    var tempVal = $('#target').val();
    var isNumber = $.isNumeric(tempVal);
    alert(isNumber);
});
```

Then whenever the input's value changes it will execute that code.  You could also add a button with a `click()` listener that you can press after you update it.

http://jsfiddle.net/n50ocyv6/1/

You could also manually set the value for the input element like this

```
<input type="text" id="target" value="4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The content in the **Result** panel isn't persistent. It refreshes every time you click **Run**. That's the reason why you always get `False` in the alert box.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Removed the question from my answer.